# Creating a game using Jquery, huge issue involving an object 'removing' another that I don't know how to fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a game using Jquery however I do have a big problem which I would appreciate help with.

First of all here are my codes.

Html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style20.css"><title>     Jquery spel</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){ 
    var spelLeftMax = $('#spelplan').width();
    var spelLeftMin = $('#box1').width();
    var spelTopMax = $('#spelplan').height();
    var spelTopMin = $('#box1').height();

    var x = $('#box1').position().left + $('#box1').width();
    var y = $('#box1').position().top + $('#box1').height();


    if (e.keyCode ==39){
        if (x < spelLeftMax) {
            $("#box1").animate({left: '+=20px'}, 0);
        }
    } 

    else if (e.keyCode ==37) {
        if (x > spelLeftMin) {
            $("#box1").animate({left: '-=20px'}, 0);
        }
    }

    else if (e.keyCode ==38) {
 if (y > spelLeftMin) {
    $("#box1").animate({top: '-=20px'}, 0);
    }
    }

    else if (e.keyCode ==40) {
  if (y < spelTopMax) {
    $("#box1").animate({top: '+=20px'}, 0)
 }
 }

    else if (e.keyCode ==38) 
        $("#box1").animate({top: '-=20px'}, 0);
    else if (e.keyCode ==40) 
        $("#box1").animate({top: '+=20px'}, 0); 
    });

setInterval(spawnrand,2250);
});

function spawnrand(){
var spelplanWidth = $('#spelplan').width();
var spelplanHeight = $('#spelplan').height();
var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random()*spelplanHeight));
var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random()*spelplanWidth));
var element = $("<div class='rand'></div>").css('left',randPosX).css('top',randPosY);
$("#spelplan").append(element);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="col-12 col-m-12">
<h1>Titel</h1>
</header>

<button class="new_pos">New position</button>


<div id="spelplan">
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="rand_pos" class="rand"></div>
<div id="pos_log" class="log">x: 0<br />y: 0</div>
<button class="new_pos">New position</button>
<br>
<p>Lives:</p>
<p>Score:</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
        *{
    box-sizing : border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

body {
background-color: black;
}

header {
position:absolute;
top:50px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}



#rand_pos{
position: absolute;
top:20%;
left: 30%;
z-index: 10;
}

#box1 {
background-color:red;
height:50px;
width:50px;
position:absolute;
left:30%;
top:150px;

}
p {
position:relative;
left:10px;
color:white;
}
#spelplan {
position:absolute;
left:25%;
top:20%;
height:600px;
width:600px;
background-color:blue;
border-style:double;
border-radius:40px;

}


.rand {
   background-color:green;
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    z-index:3;
    }


.new_pos {
background: #ccc;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #555;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.new_pos:hover {
background: #bbb;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #222;
}


.new_pos:active {
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
background: #aaa;
}


*:focus {
 outline: none;
}



.new_pos {
 position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}








/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
/* For tablets: */
.col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
img {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
}
```

So the part I need help with is how I make the object you play as "#box1" consume the small green balls "rand". As you can see I dont have a clue how to even start with this part so I need a lot of help.

Once again I would really appreciate any help I can get, thanks in advance!

By the way i'm open to suggestions for changing the title, had a hard time trying to word it in a good way.

Comment: What does "consume" mean? What's going wrong?

Comment: @Pointy I want the object you play as "#box1" to 'eat' the small green objects "rand" when the "#box1" moves ontop of the small green objects so that they disappear.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for us, then we can advise/assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game has a loop, caused by the key press. Assuming your actor is then moved all you would need to do is check if his coords (x,y) are within bounds of an enemy's (x,y) in which case he would be over one. This would then fire a function (consume) that would run an animation on one or both sprites(enemy and actor) remove the enemy, adjust your score. If the enemies can move independently of the actors loop, you would run the same code here when they are moved by your game loop.

So, in short.

1. Create a function for consuming (this handles the UI animation of both sprites, sound and score adjust, removing the enemy sprite)
2. Create a function who loops the enemies to check if they are under/over the actor using a map around their sprite (x,y,w,h). If you get a hit call your consumer function to pass the enemy sprite and actor
3. Call the function in point 2 in your game loop, when you move a sprite.

To do this you are better off scripting your game in a more object based fashion where code can be re-used. This the game focus's around sprites (player,enemy) I have coded a sprite class that has all of the functions built in to move, animate and detect collisions with other sprites.

To create the player sprite we just call

```
var player = new sprite("box1", 200, 200, 50, 50, "player", game);
```

We can call methods on him to do stuff that our player requires to do:

```
player.up();
player.dowm();
player.destroy(); // removes from dom destroys instance.
```

We can now add an enemy to our playing field:

```
var alien = new sprite("alien", 400, 400, 20, 20, "spaceship", game);
```

and when we move our alien check if he collides with our alien

```
alien.left();
if (alien.collidesWith(player)===true) //dosomething;
```

The next trick is to store game sprites in a cache (array) so that we can find them and access their properties, methods

The code below is a re-write that does all of this. The fiddle shows a working game with the score incrementing as you consume enemies.

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sprites = [];
  var enemies = [];
  var game = $("#spelplan");
  var score = 0;
  var el_score = $("#score")


  //
  // First things first we all want to score points
  //
  function SCORE(pts) {
    score += pts
    el_score.text(score);
  }

  //
  // We spin up a simple sprite class that can be re-used, It's simple
  // params; id,x,y,w,h,class,area
  // The area is the realm where the sprite exists - in our case all in one div.
  // this would allow you to bind sprites into different realms - areas of your game.
  // methods: up, down, left,right - binding the sprite within the realms box x,y,w,h
  //
  // Exercise:
  // Modify, extend the sprite class so we can specify how much a sprite can move ie 20px or 10px.
  //
  var sprite = function(id, x, y, w, h, _class, view, collisionDetect) {
    this.view = view;
    this.id = id
    this.x = x + "px";
    this.y = y + "px";
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;

    this.el = $("<div id='" + this.id + "' class='" + _class + "'></div>").css('left', this.x).css('top', this.y);
    view.append(this.el);

    this.x = function() {
      return this.el.position().left;
    }
    this.y = function() {
      return this.el.position().top;
    }

    this.up = function() {
      if (this.y() > 0) {
        this.el.animate({
          top: '-=25px'
        }, 0);
        if (collisionDetect) collisionDetect(this);
      }
    };
    this.down = function() {
      if (this.y() < this.view.height() - this.height) {
        this.el.animate({
          top: '+=25px'
        }, 0);
        if (collisionDetect) collisionDetect(this);
      }
    };
    this.left = function() {
      if (this.x() > 0) {

        this.el.animate({
          left: '-=25px'
        }, 0);
        if (collisionDetect) collisionDetect(this);
      }
    };
    this.right = function() {
      if (this.x() + this.width < this.view.width()) {
        this.el.animate({
          left: '+=25px'
        }, 0);
        if (collisionDetect) collisionDetect(this);
      }


    };
    // returns back the x,y's and the z's of a sprites
    this.getPos = function() {
      var pos, width, height;
      pos = this.el.position();
      width = this.el.width();
      height = this.el.height();
      return [
        [pos.left, pos.left + width],
        [pos.top, pos.top + height]
      ];
    };
    // checks if any two positions are a collision
    this.comparePos = function(p1, p2) {
      var r1, r2;
      r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
      r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
      return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
    };
    // returns true if the passed sprites collides with this sprite
    this.collidesWith = function(sprite) {
      var pos1 = this.getPos(),
        pos2 = sprite.getPos();
      return this.comparePos(pos1[0], pos2[0]) && this.comparePos(pos1[1], pos2[1]);
    };

    // add to our sprite object so we can reference.
    sprites.push(this);

  };
  //
  // Your existing spawn, now it just calls my sprite class with new and the params for our enemy.
  // My class will remember all the enemies within its own internal cache sprites, this now makes
  // it easier for us to detect what is going on since now we can ref any sprite on the screen
  // sprites[0].up() moves the first sprite up.
  //
  function spawnrand() {
    var spelplanWidth = game.width();
    var spelplanHeight = game.height();
    var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * spelplanHeight));
    var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * spelplanWidth));
    // create enemy, store him in array so we can find him,
    var enemy = new sprite("enemy" + sprites.length + 1, randPosY, randPosX, 15, 15, "rand", game);
    enemies.push(enemy);
  }

  // set score
  SCORE(0);


  var player = new sprite("box1", 200, 200, 50, 50, "player", game,
    function(sprite) {

      // detect if the player is over an enemy.
      sprites.forEach(function(sprite) {
        // primitive but ignores the plater sprite since he is not an enemy!
        if (sprite.id !== "box1" && player.collidesWith(sprite)) {
          //
          // Here is where the action happens, animate the destruction
          // of your enemy - add up the score
          // TODO:
          // Add a destroy method to our sprite class, removes him from dom
          // and from our sprite array!
          sprite.el.fadeOut();
          SCORE(100);
        }

      })


    });
  setInterval(spawnrand, 3000);

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      player.left();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      player.right();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      player.up();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      player.down();
    }
  });






});
```

There are a couple of changes to your HTML and css mainly you don't need your box1 and rand enemy added in your raw HTML, the game adds them if for you.

Here is a fiddle of the game working - destroy as many enemies as you can for hi-score.

https://jsfiddle.net/erLv5rwb/3/

Would be more addictive if you added a time delay that removes the enemies or reduces their value when they are eaten, the faster you catch them the more you score. This is easy to do by adding a pts value to the sprite calls and reducing it over time.

I hope this primitive but useful insight will help you build great games. Many many years ago simple code like this powered one or two games that sold a million.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the info, could you please help me with the coding aswell? I'm new to coding and would really appreciate it. Here is a fiddle i created https://jsfiddle.net/erLv5rwb/

Comment: I have updated my answer your game is now working - Your a lucky first timer, many years ago I did this for a living. Stack overflow is not a code building site, but if this gets's you started, I'm not complaining.

Comment: This is not perfect - right now my simple game does not destroy the enemy it just fades him out this is why as you run over him you may score multiple times. You need to add the destroy code that removes him from the dom.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and for all the help you have given me I really appreciate it, I would not have been able to figure this out without you!

Comment: My pleasure. I am taking a coffee break and adding the destroy so that the enemies are removed from dom, I will post a new fiddle. As this should give you enough to crack on.

Comment: If i can win the accepted answer that would be a reward. Thank you.

Comment: Here is an updated version that shows how i extend my sprite class to allow sprites to be destroyed, enemies to have different PTS values when consumed, and for enemies to destroy themselves after 5 seconds. Again primitive but informative. https://jsfiddle.net/erLv5rwb/4/

Comment: Once again thank you so much, your idea made the game a lot more interesting than what I had in mind. Thanks for existing <3

Comment: If you could accept my answer as the winner that would be a great bonus thank you.